# How to use a range instead of a single value for an axis tick in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I don't want to mess with the graph itself, but I want to change the axis tick so that it reads a different value. Right now my axis looks like 0, 1, 2, 3....24. I want it to look like: 0-1,1-2,3-4...23-24.

Is it possible to just change the text without changing my graph?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you making a histogram? (i.e. using a Bin field on the row or column shelf?) Is your Bin field discrete (blue) or continuous (green)?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore I am making a line graph. But if it was converted to a histogram the bin field would be continuous

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement this would be by converting your column in to a discrete value and changing the alias for value 0 to 0-1, 1 to 1-2... and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this, it turned from a line to a histogram. Not sure how to change the alias - still rather new to Tableau. Thank you for taking the time to make a suggestion.

Comment: To set the mark type click on the word Automatic on the marks card and choose the mark type of your choice, as in lines

Comment: To define aliases, right click on any discrete dimension field in the left sidebar data pane, and choose edit aliases

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a calculated field and return the range based on the values. This gives you more control if you would like customize your range in the future. There will be an issue with sorting which you will need to work out.

Comment: Can I see an example of what you are doing? I'm rather new to Tableau and am not sure how to do this - or the issue you were mentioning with sorting.